# Выбор только перечисленных элементов в WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть `sql` запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_products p 
LEFT JOIN tb_cities c ON p.city_id=c.id 
WHERE c.city_id IN (1, 3, 6)
```

Но мне нужно чтобы из выбранных 3 идентификаторов (1, 3, 6), выбрались все перечисленные, а не только любой из них.

То есть в таблице `tb_cities` есть несколько записей с одним и тем же продуктом но с разными городами. Мне нужно чтобы продукы были в городах с `id`: 1, 3, 6; то есть `IN (1, 3, 6)`, а не продукты которые есть в одной из этих городов.

**Если я не ясно объяснил то прошу напишите**

Comment: а все - это как?

Comment: Выберутся все, но при двух условиях: а) они есть в таблице б) клиент прочитает все выбранные строки

Comment: как я понимаю, у вас продукты, которые есть в разных городах, и вы хотите, чтобы продукт одновременно был в городах 1, 3, 6? Если да, то подправьте вопрос соответствующим образом, чтобы было понятно. Пока - не понятно.

Comment: Извините сейчась подправлю вопрос. Я просто сделал копипаст и не заметил ошибку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как структура таблицы не предоставлена, запрос будет примерно такой:

```
SELECT p.product_id
FROM tb_products p 
    JOIN tb_cities c ON p.city_id=c.id 
WHERE c.id IN (1, 3, 6)
GROUP BY p.product_id
HAVING count(distinct c.id) = 3
```

Что получается - присоединяем таблицу с городами и продуктами, указываем, чтобы продукты были только в 3-х городах и смотрим, сколько уникальных городов есть для каждого продукта. Если три города - значит продукт есть и в 1, и в 3, и в 6.